# Rmarkdown PDF with kableExtra in RStudio Cloud

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, kableextra

I'm trying to compile a PDF document from RStudio Cloud, using rmarkdown as the following minimal (not) working example.

First, to be able to install some latex packages (not included in MWE) I had to install tinytex with option `force = TRUE`. Now if I run the command `pdflatex --version` I see this result:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
```

MWE is just below and if I try to knit it from my RStudio Cloud session I get this error:

> ! Use of \@startpbox doesn't match its definition.
>
> \@startpbox {l>{\raggedright \arraybackslash }p{12cm}l}
>
> l.101 ...{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{12cm}l}
>
> Error: Failed to compile MWE.tex. See MWE.log for more info.
>
> Execution halted

````
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: false
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r start, include = FALSE}
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)
```


```{r table, results = "asis"}
tbl <- tribble(~number, ~descrip, ~perc,
               "8415", "long long very long description of something. More text and stuff here.", "10%")

kableExtra::kable(tbl,
                  booktabs = TRUE,
                  longtable = TRUE,
                  col.names = c("NCM", "Description", "IPI%")) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>% 
  kableExtra::column_spec(2, width = "12cm")
```
````

The funny thing is, in my local R session, I can compile this without a problem, although I'm using TeX Live 2017 installed manually.

Does anyone know what's happening here? I know it's a Latex problem, but somehow it's the interaction of knitr (or pandoc?) and kableExtra that is causing some sort of conflict.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I copied your example into my own Rstudio Cloud and it worked. I had to install "tinytex", "kableExtra", "tibble", "bookdown" but once these were installed, it worked.  https://rstudio.cloud/project/157597

Comment: Thank you @awchisholm. I must have done something wrong in my first attempt to configure TeXLive in RStudio Cloud. I restarted the project from ground, installed needed packages and then installed TinyTex, and now everything is working properly.